# How to change input text to lowercase in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I want to have an input field to take email from the user for login. I already have all the email validations applied. But now I want to convert the text to lowercase as soon as the user inserts the email.

```
 <div class="form-group mb-3">
 <div class="">
 <input name="email" class="form-control required" type="email" required placeholder="Email ID" ng-pattern="emailFormat" ng-model="admin.username">
 </div>
 <span style="color: red" class="error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.pattern">
 Please enter a valid email
 </span>
 </div>

 //Email format
 $scope.emailFormat = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._\-]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9.]{2,5}$/;
```

Anyone can please help me how can I convert the upper case letter to lowercase directly in the ng-model? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `toLowerCase`?

Comment: use admin.username.toLowerCase()

Comment: Try this {{value | lowercase}}

Answer (score 0):

you can use method 'onchange' in your input and create a function and use method toLowercase (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp)

Comment: This isn't the angular way - `ng-change` not `onchange`